# systemd: Unknown lvalue 'Condition ...' in section 'Service'

Tags: systemd

When I look at my journal I see entries like,

```
systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/my-installer.service:12] Unknown lvalue 'ConditionFirstBoot' in section 'Service'
systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/myl-installer.service:13] Unknown lvalue 'ConditionPathExists' in section 'Service'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your service has

```
ConditionFirstBoot=
ConditionPathExists=
```

In the `[Service]` section of the unit. And it needs to be in the `[Unit]` section.